# Is it possible to get the artifact name from the mule sdk?

Tags: mule, mule4, mule-sdk

Is it possible to get the artifact (app) name using the mule sdk when developing a custom mule connector?

I can get the artifact name by creating a parameter and having the user pass it in:

```
@Parameter
private String artifactName;
```

but can it be retrieved from an injected service?

Comment: Why do you want to access the application name inside a connector? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For debugging purposes.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a concern of a connector. Probably better to use the logging system for that.

Comment: But if I wanted to access the artifact name, is it possible and how could I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifact name and application name could be different. The more clean approach is to add a configuration to the module/connector for the application name and set it in the application. If the user sets it to the built-in placeholder`${app.name}` it will contain the actual application name.